# What is good way to customize Sylius?

Tags: symfony, customization, sylius

One year ago, I used Sylius version 0.13.0 for my project E-commerce. I customized many things in the bundles of Sylius (WebBundle, AddressingBundle, ProductBundle....), the code of Sylius in the directory src. It's not problem

Now I have new project E-commerce, I see the newest version is 1.0.0-alpha.1, many things change, now Sylius is a package in vendor. I want to customize Sylius but I think it's not good idea if I modify code in package Sylius because I want to get the updates of Sylius after.

So I want to ask: what is good way to customize code Sylius and the order procedure ? Any suggestions ? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade to alpha was from 0.19.0.

The suggested way to customize Sylius is currently here - http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/index.html

Please have a look and give us feedback ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will give you feedback

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change Sylius core, the only way to customize it, is overriding bundles:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html
- http://docs.sylius.org/en/stable/bundles/general/index.html

However it also doesn't prevent you from any changes in the future... What's more Sylius when moved to alpha-1.0 from (I guess) 0.16, also broke many BC rules, so it doesn't help in extending Sylius functionalities *(more: http://sylius.org/blog/sylius-roadmap-update)*.